# System.InvalidOperationException в System.Drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть функция `UpdateImageData`, которая меняет цвет пикселей `PictureBox` в отдельном потоке:

```cs
var bmp = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;
var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(tile, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
var bmpRaw = (byte*) bmpData.Scan0.ToPointer();
// Здесь происходит изменение через bmpRaw[]
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

При взаимодействии с окном (изменение размера, перемещение и т.п.) вылетает ошибка

```cs
Application.Run(new Form1());
/* System.InvalidOperationException: "Область растрового изображения уже заблокирована."
    в System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
    в System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
    в System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
    в System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
*/
```

Блок try/catch не обрабатывает эту ошибку.
Скорее всего, что при взаимодействии с окном происходит одновременная перерисовка `PictureBox`
из двух потоков, но я не знаю как заставить их подождать друг друга.

Если использовать `pictureBox1.Invoke(UpdateImageData)`, то сильно теряется скорость обновления изображения.
Ещё был вариант использовать копию изображения (код ниже), но тогда видно чересстрочную отрисовку (медленно обновляется всё изображения, вместо участка, что изначально было очевидно).

```cs
var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
// ...
pictureBox1.Image = (Image) bmp;
```

Comment: Самый простой способ - перестать использовать PictureBox не по назначению, а за обновление изображения у вас отвечает сейчас именно он и на это поведение вы ни как не повлияете. Хотите рисовать в WinForms самостоятельно, да еще и в нескольких потоках - наследуйтесь UserControl и реализуйте отрисовку как вам надо со всеми необходимыми блокировками и ожиданиями. А PictureBox предназначен для отображения готовых статических изображений (на счет анимированных GIF не уверен, не проверял)  и не предполагает пользовательский интерактив.

Comment: Отрисовка в моём коде только в одном потоке, второй поток - системный (или как правильно будет его назвать), который занимается перерисовкой всего окна.

Comment: Это вы думаете что в одном. На самом деле при перерисовке всего окна - перерисовывается и PictureBox, который вызывает System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage, который использует аналог LockBits в неуправляемом коде, для ускорения своей работы. Ваша беда сейчас в том, что вы не контролируете кто и когда получает доступ к изображению и перерисовывает его, и пока вы не будете это контролировать - будете ловить исключения, т.к. изменить поведение PictuBox вы не сможете, хотя можете унаследоваться от него, но это не сильно отличается от предложения наследоваться от UserConrol

Answer (score 0):

Все действия по рисованию или изменению чего-либо в графических элементах формы (например, изменение надписи в Label) должны выполняться из основного - главного потока. Если у вас есть потребность рисовать из параллельных потоков, то на момент вывода на экран надо передавать управление главному потоку с помощью Invoke(), например, вот так:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (working)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
             try
             {
                  label1.Text="new text";
                  DrawMyPictures();
                  pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                  Application.DoEvents();
             }
             catch
             {
                  MessageBox.Show("Draw Exception!");
             }
        }));
    }
}).Start();
```

При рисовании происходят блокировки, и система налетает на такую блокировку, когда сама пытается рисовать, поэтому нельзя давать ей шанса.